# LINQ IQueryable can't evaluate expression, though IEnumerable can

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that returns a collection of elements from my DB ordered by some parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks(int page, int count, string order, string direction)
    {
        var books = _context.Books
            .Select(b => b)
            .Include(b => b.Author)
            .AsQueryable();
            
        switch (direction)
        {
            case "Ascending":
                books = books.OrderBy(b => typeof(Book).GetProperty(order)!.GetValue(b));
                break;
            case "Descending":
                books = books.OrderByDescending(b => typeof(Book).GetProperty(order)!.GetValue(b));
                break;
        }

        return books
            .Skip((page - 1) * count)
            .Take(count)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
```

When I try to execute this code I don't get any exceptions, though I still get **fail** in my logs.

> .OrderBy(b => __GetProperty_0.GetValue(b))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

But as soon as I change initial select to be

```
 var books = _context.Books
   .Select(b => b)
   .Include(b => b.Author)
   .AsEnumerable()
```

It work fine.

My guess on this issue is that it might appear because of `OrderBy()` inner expression that is `Func<Book, object?>`.

I want to know what is the actual cause of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Correct, the DB knows nothing about `typeof(Book)` and cannot use reflection. You need make order an `Expression<Func<Book,string>>` to pass into the method OR if the columns have various types (string, int, decimal, ...) create a switch statement on the `order` parameter and create each getter expression in that switch statement.

Comment: LINQ *can* evaluate the expression. The error says that this expression can't be translated to SQL. That means you're using a database, not LINQ to Objects. Don't use expressions that can't be translated. If an expression is so complicated it would result in a bad, slow query even if it could be translated

Comment: It seems like the *real* question is how to add a dynamically generated order field, not LINQ itself. Where does the field name come from? Configuration? A dropdown? An OData query? Can it be something other than a field name? In a dropdown, the Value could be an `Expression<Func<Book,string>>` instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

> LINQ IQueryable can't evaluate expression, though IEnumerable can

It seems that you are using some ORM (based on the error I would argue that it is EF Core), so it will need to translate provided [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) into SQL, and translating reflection is not supported.

One option is to use switch to manually map the incoming property name to the actual ordering expression:

```
Expression<Func<Book, object>> f = order.ToLowerInvariant() switch
{
    "Name" => b => b.Name,
    "Title" => b => b.Title,
    // ...
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
};
switch (direction)
{
    case "Ascending":
        books = books.OrderBy(f);
        break;
    case "Descending":
        books = books.OrderByDescending(f);
        break;
}
```

If you want more dynamic approach - you can try building expression tree yourself:

```cs
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book));
var propertyOrField = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, order);
var f = Expression.Lambda<Func<Author, object>>(propertyOrField, parameterExpression);
// use f like in the previous snippet.
```

But I would argue that it is more brittle approach.

Also you can look into using 3rd party library like [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core#systemlinqdynamiccore) which allows doing something like `books.OrderBy("Name")`.